# No Sound after playing around with pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I was trying to be able to monitor my microphone input and I ran into this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic?answertab=active#tab-top). <sup>(How to hear my voice in speakers with a mic?)</sup>

I followed Charl Botha's advice, and launched pulseaudio volume control, then typed into the terminal that I used to launch the application

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

after doing this, nothing happened except that now there is no sound at all!

I have checked all pulseaudio volume control settings and everything seems to be fine, yet there still is no sound. Guest account has sound, but mine does not.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To get pulseaudio back and running you can run the command `pulseaudio --start` or by using the `Alt+F2` combo for running commands via the dash, just type pulseaudio and you'll get a result that'll get it running.