# Apply LADSPA plugin to input (microphone)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, input-devices

Similar to [How can I apply a LADSPA plugin to a PulseAudio stream?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream), but I'm trying to apply the plugins to my source, not a sink. Basically, I want other people to hear my voice with plugins applied to it.

Let's say I have a input: `INPUT='alsa_input.usb-mic-00-mic.analog-stereo'`

And a filter:

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_low_pass master=$INPUT plugin=cmt label=lpf control=200
```

Doesn't really work. I'm able to select the filter on `pavucontrol` but only for my output.

I don't want to install JACK, it caused me a few problems on VOIP clients.

Answer (score 2):

To apply a LADSPA filter on our microphone input we need to combine the following:

1. Load a LADSPA plugin to a newly created sink (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream))

   ```
   pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=<yourname> master=<sinkname> plugin=<plugin> label=<label> control=<option1>,<option2>,[...]
   ```
2. Loopback the microphone input to this sink (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic))

   ```
   pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
   ```

To record this filtered output we choose `<name_of_ladspa_sink>.monitor` as a recording source.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I can hear myself with the plugins enabled if I change to the monitor on the "Playback" tab, but when I'm trying to do this on Skype and I select the monitor on the "Recording" => "All Streams" => <ladspa monitor> I get no sound. I've tried to change to every possible combination of loopback/stream and I can't hear anything on Skype (made a call to another computer on my network), no matter what.

Comment: @braindamage The name you need for recording is `nameofsink.monitor` but there may be issues with Skype.

Comment: yes that's what I'm using, I tried both from the terminal and also from pavucontrol