# Using LADSPA Plugins to have a noise gate to my microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am want to apply a noise gate to my microphone. But I dont know why.
I see that LADSPA Plugins can do that but i dont know how to set them up.
If someone can help me with LADSPA or has a different application that I could use with PulseAudio, tell me.
I need this, quick!

Comment: For LADSPA usage with pulseaudio see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream - there is a gate in the [SWH plugins](http://plugin.org.uk/ladspa-swh/docs/ladspa-swh.html#tth_sEc2.47), or from [TAP Dynamics](http://tap-plugins.sourceforge.net/ladspa/dynamics.html) - it's a bit trial and error to find appropriate parameters.

Comment: Every time I try to add this module, it says "Module load failed" I am using this code `pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_out master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo plugin=tap_dynamics_st label=tap_dynamics_st control=4,4,2,2` @Takkat

Comment: You missed some options,  see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

#### LADSPA-plugins to Pulse Audio

See this question on how to load and use LADSPA-plugins with pulseaudio:

- [How can I apply a LADSPA plugin to a PulseAudio stream?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream)

#### TAP dynamics

For a compressor plugin we can use the [TAP dynamics plugin](http://tap-plugins.sourceforge.net/ladspa/dynamics.html) from the [tap-plugins [image: Install tap-plugins]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tap-plugins).

The syntax for this plugin to load with pulseaudio is as follows:

```
pactl load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=LADSPA master=<sink-name> \
plugin=tap_dynamics_st label=tap_dynamics_st \
control=<attack>,<release>,<offset gain>,<makeup gain>,<stereo mode>,<function>
```

To get this plugin loaded we need to fill in **all** options above within the following possible range (from [TAP documentation](http://tap-plugins.sourceforge.net/ladspa/dynamics.html), also stored locally in `usr/share/doc/tap-plugins/`):

```
                   min.     default     max.
Attack (ms)         4        125        500
Release (ms)        4        502       1000
Offset Gain (dB)   -20        0          20
Makeup Gain (dB)   -20        0          20
Stereo Mode [2]     ?*        ?*         ?* *not documented well!
Function            0         0          14
```

The following `function` is selected by its number:

`0`  2:1 compressor at -6 dB
`1`  2:1 compressor at -9 dB
`2`  2:1 compressor at -12 dB
`3`  2:1 compressor at -18 dB
`4`  2.5:1 compressor at -12 dB
`5`  3:1 compressor at -12 dB
`6`  3:1 compressor at -15 dB
`7`  Compressor/Gate
`8`  Expander
`9`  Hard limiter at -6 dB
`10` Hard limiter at -12 dB
`11` Hard gate at -35 dB
`12` Soft limiter
`13` Soft knee compressor/gate
`14` Soft gate below -36 dB

#### Apply to microphone source

To apply the LADSPA effect on a microphone source we can loopback the microphone input to this sink:

- [Apply LADSPA plugin to input (microphone)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551984/apply-ladspa-plugin-to-input-microphone)

#### Using JACK sound server

For a more professional audio processing we may also consider running the [JACK sound server](http://jackaudio.org/) where we can add plugins for LADSPA effects (e.g. [jack-rack [image: Install jack-rack]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jack-rack)).

#### Post-processing with Audacity

Post-processing of exisiting audio files or recordings can be done with [Audacity [image: Install audacity]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity).

Comment: I used this solution that you sent. It loads, but how can I set it to take in the audio from the microhpone and make the ladspa like a "virtual" mic in the system that I could use for recording? Now no audio is going into ladspa plugin!

Comment: I can apply the filter to my google chrome stream(when I am watching a vid) and it has huge effects, but when applied to my mic, it doesnt have that effect at all!  am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Elderzz: actually the loopback device should work (at least it did for me). You could also try to assign a duplex profile to your sound card.

Comment: How do I do that? @Takkat I also hear myself with the ladspa sink unmuted

Comment: @Elderzz: sorry for the delay (/me busy). I am a bit confused as to where your issue is at the moment. It is crucial to follow this sequence: 1. load the LADSPA module 2. switch to the LADSPA sink for output 3. load the loopback module. A duplex profile can be selected with **pavucontrol** configuration tab or via `pactl set-card-profile <card> <profile>`.

Comment: I know @Takkat I did all of that, but how do i record the output of the sink?  Also, it seems like the plugin has no effects to my mic audio.

Comment: It should have the same effect you hear when playing any other stream. To record the sink choose a `name_of_sink.monitor ` as an input source for the recording application. Again, this choice can best be made with **pavucontrol**. It's not only you who finds this to be confusing and rather complicated.

Comment: You may also play with a  plugin effect that can't be overheard to get a grasp on the right settings (e.g. with the pitch shift I mentioned in my post I linked to above).

Comment: I know the parameters and that but i dont know how to apply it to the mic!

Comment: @Elderzz: I see - no, unfortunately the LADSPA plugins can only be applied to a sink, not to a source. A so far not-yet-existent module-ladspa-source would be really nice to have ;-). That's why we have to loop-back the source to a sink to be able to apply LADSPA effects.

Comment: Do you maybe know of a application that would help me do that? Maybe an app that adds plugins to ALSA or PulseAudio.

Comment: @Elderzz: for professional audio processing [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/applications/) as a sound server with effects plugins e.g. [JACKRack](http://jack-rack.sourceforge.net/) may be a better (though harder) approach. JACK is the default sound server in Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: I tried to setup jack, but I dont know how to use it cuz whenever i start a jack server, my pulseaudio is not working(I tried with a vid on youtube and it just stops doenst move anywhere) I cant find how to correctly set it up @Takkat

Comment: JACK is an entirely different sound server, and it is not easy to set up. See  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/What%20is%20JACK for a start.

Comment: I know how to setup  jack, the only thing is the connections. in qjactl i dont see chrome, or skype or any of those...  @Takkat

Comment: What is `master=<sink-name>` supposed to be?

Comment: @qubodup `<sink-name>` is the name of the sink you wish the plugin to be applied to. See `pactl list short sinks`  for sinks in your system.