# Loading LADSPA plugin not working (Module load failed.)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Following the advice of @Takkat ([Apply LADSPA plugin to input (microphone)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551984/apply-ladspa-plugin-to-input-microphone)), I tried to apply a plugin (SC4 Mono) to a newly created sink:

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa-sink master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_10.1.analog-stereo plugin=sc4m_1916 label=SC4mono control=0,100,400,0,0,3.25,0,0,0
```

The name of the sink was checked with the following command:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

The name of the plugin was checked in the the folder:

```
/usr/lib/ladspa/
```

But running that command in the terminal returns:

```
Module load failed.
```

I use the default settings for the SC4 Mono plugin when loaded with Audacity for my command. In the end I would like to apply the plugin SC4 Mono to the Microphone Input of my soundcard, so that other programs receive the altered signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where two errors in my command:

**Original command:**

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa-sink master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_10.1.analog-stereo plugin=sc4m_1916 label=SC4mono control=0,100,400,0,0,3.25,0,0,0
Module load failed.
```

**Label changed to sc4m:**

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa-sink master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_10.1.analog-stereo plugin=sc4m_1916 label=sc4m control=0,100,400,0,0,3.25,0,0,0
Module load failed.
```

**Control values changed:**

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa-sink master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_10.1.analog-stereo plugin=sc4m_1916 label=SC4mono control=1,1.5,401,-30,20,5,12
Module load failed.
```

**Label and control values changed – success:**

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa-sink master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_10.1.analog-stereo plugin=sc4m_1916 label=sc4m control=1,1.5,401,-30,20,5,12
```

**Change summary:**

```
label=sc4m
control=1,1.5,401,-30,20,5,12
```

The correct labels for the steve harris plugins (http://plugin.org.uk/ladspa-swh/docs/ladspa-swh.html) seem to be the first part within the parenthesis next to the plugin name.

The control values must also be carefully chosen.