# Notify me for voice when I am wearing headphones

Tags: music

I keep listening to music with my headphones all day and there are people who keep calling me but it does not always work for them. So, I was wondering if there was an application that could notify me if someone is shouting or if the doorbell is ringing. If not is there something else that I could do.

Comment: So a sound detector?

Comment: but it should not disturb me when there is some tv or bacground noise or something

Comment: So decided by a loud volume? It's still not possible with current free software to detect certain sounds.

Comment: i actually tried to use audible to see the graph but noise and someones call both look the same that's why I had to ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use microphone input port along line output as headphone output with `jackd` and `qjackctl`. See here for solution [How to hear my voice in speakers with a mic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic)

Don't forget to place your microfone near the door to your room and make it less sensitive to avoid noise! ;)

Comment: but i don't think that doing this will let me listen to music or watch movies etc.

Comment: @akabhirav why not? you can listen music and will hear anyone who asks you near the door

Comment: but will it not add noise to the music ??

Comment: @akabhirav Ok, use sound sensor with AVR microcontroller connected to your computer with serial and a Python script to mute your output if discrete signal is on... Is it better solution for you?

Comment: But do not be surprised when it will always turn off the sound at the slightest movement in the corridor