# Electric guitar through iRig in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound, hardware

I have an [iRig](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irig1/) pre-amp for my electric guitar. Can I use it in Ubuntu? What software I need?

Answer (score 2):

AmpliTube works perfectly in Xubuntu via Wine.

“WineASIO provides an ASIO to JACK driver for WINE. ASIO is the most common Windows low-latency driver, so is commonly used in audio workstation programs.”

#### Install Wine and Jack:

```
sudo apt-get install wine jackd qjackctl
```

#### Install WineAsio .deb

Download  and install this package

```
wget http://www.lucamazzilli.it/downloads/wineasio_0.9.0-1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i wineasio_0.9.0-1_i386.deb
```

Install dependencies

- jack 1

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libjack-dev
  ```
- jack 2

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev
  ```

Download and extract

```
wget http://leaseweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wineasio/wineasio-0.9.0.tar.gz

tar -zxvf wineasio-*

cd wineasio
```

Get the source asio.h (file:asio.h  http://sourceforge.net/projects/wineasio/files/wineasio-0.9.0.tar.gz/) than copy to your source folder and:

make

```
sudo make install
```

if you get an error like this:

```
exmple@pc:~/wineasio$ sudo make install
if [ -d /usr/lib32/wine ]; then cp wineasio.dll.so /usr/lib32/wine; else cp wineasio.dll.so /usr/lib/wine; fi
```

just copy wineasio.dll.so on the correct folder in old fashioned way:

- 64bit

  ```
  sudo cp wineasio.dll.so /usr/lib32/wine
  ```
- 32bit

  ```
  sudo cp wineasio.dll.so /usr/lib/wine
  ```

You must register wine library

```
regsvr32 wineasio.dll
```

#### Configure Wine to use alsa and jack

```
winecfg
```

select audio tab, than pick Jack Driver and Alsa Driv.

Comment: FYI so does Guitar rig 5, it is nice but expensive.

Comment: Price and quality usually go up together - usually lol. But good to know!

Comment: `http://www.lucamazzilli.it/downloads/wineasio_0.9.0-1_i386.deb` is not found. Can you update the link?

Comment: My PC is 64 bit. Should I still use `regsvr32`?

Comment: You can try https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32045 - Personal choice i use 32 for myself.

Comment: Or https://sourceforge.net/projects/wineasio/

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level you just want the sound from a mic input to come out of the speakers, which you an do in a number of ways.  Here's one:
[How to hear my voice in speakers with a mic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic)

There is also a program called [Rakarrack](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/rakarrack/) which apparently does guitar effects.

Comment: It's not so simple. The iRig is connected through USB.

Answer (score 1):

As you say your preamp is USB, here is how I use my USB preamp in Ubuntu.

First you need `jack` to control the interface

```
sudo apt-get install qjackctl jackd
```

and  `Rakarrack` as the amp simulator

```
sudo apt-get install  rakarrack
```

For setup run `qjackctl` from `dash` and set it up with your usb device in the `interface` section and your speakers as the `output`, then tweak the other settings to your liking, here are my settings

[image]

You may also need to click `connect` in `qjackctl` and connect the `input` to the `output`, this can be done in just a click or two.

Now restart `qjackctl` and run `Rakarrack` (`qjackctl` MUST run first), if you set your interfaces correctly that should be all you need, you will here your guitar from the speakers and can use `Rakarrack` to set up some nice tones ;)

Comment: `Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "jack2"` ... ?

Comment: Did you mean `jackd2`?

Comment: My bad should be `jackd`

Comment: FYI It may be a dependency of `qjackctl`, so it may be install by just that, but I can't remember.

Comment: Note that `jackd` / `jackd2` (qjackctl is a graphical interface to that and indeed has all necessary packages as dependecies) runs _on top of_ the underlying ALSA architecture. Without ALSA drivers there's nothing you can do to get the interface running, as I already said in my answer. And, USB is irrelevant here, that's just one of multiple buses an interface / its drivers might use. You can use jack just as well with an internal sound card.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "Without ALSA drivers there's nothing you can do to get the interface running," Works for me.

Comment: @markkirby: well, because there _is_ an ALSA driver for your interface. Apparently one that comes with the `alsa-common` package, which is installed by default. Thus for you everything is fine, you don't even notice anything about ALSA. Unfortunately, it looks a lot like the OP has an interface that's _not_ supported by ALSA, and then all the higher-level stuff like `jack`, let alone Rakarrack, is no use either.

Answer (score 0):

To properly use any audio interface with Linux, you first of all need a working [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) driver. You may already be out of luck with the iRig there. If you have

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-firmware-loaders
```

And you connect the interface but it doesn't show up in Pulseaudio (or `aplay -l`), then I'm afraid it's likely going to be very hard to get it to work on Ubuntu at all. You may consider getting some other interface with reliable ALSA drivers.

If the interface does show up, then you should next get jack to do the patching.

```
sudo apt-get install qjackctl
```

Finally, you'll want some way to *process* the signal. For sure, this *can* be done with the big commercial programs like Guitar Rig, Amplitude, or (better) BiasFX, iZotope Trash... but I'd think twice before Wine-infiltrating a Linux install with such closed-source behemoths.

Before you do so, I'd recommend you check out [Pure Data](http://puredata.info/). It's *completely* different from those programs – not at all specialised at simulating existing guitar amps/pedals; instead it gives you really nice ways to design completely new sound effects, completely from scratch. (But, this is definitely nothing for *quickly getting some impressive standard sould*; perhaps Rakarrack will serve you if that's what you want.)

Comment: Please note that the iRig is connected through USB.

Comment: Whether it's USB or Firewire or PCI is secondary; if there's a suitable ALSA driver it'll _know_ how the interface is supposed to be connected. Only, I fear there isn't such a driver that would work for the iRig.