# How can screen recording software record the call audio of both the local person (on the mic) and the remote person (on the speakers)?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, desktop-recording, pavucontrol

I use SimpleScreenRecorder to record our group meetings from a Firefox screen of Jitsi. I use a USB headset and would like to record both the audio of what I say in my headset microphone and the audio of what others say that comes out of my headset earphones. I don't know how to do this and hope for guidance on audio configuration to enable me to do this, or some other options.

The program I'm using can be installed in the following way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install simplescreenrecorder
```

[image]

I have looked at the various audio streams using `pavucontrol`. When recording using the microphone of the headset, it is the "*Clear Chat Comfort USB Headset Analog Mono*" stream that is in use. When playing something using the earphones of the headset, it is the "*Clear Chat Comfort USB Headset Analog Stereo*" stream that is in use. I see no reactivity of the various streams labelled "monitor" and so on.

Is there some audio configuration I have not considered or implemented? What might be a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route your microphone through your speakers. That might do the trick:

- [How to hear my voice in speakers with a mic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic)

In summary:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```