# Why can't record audio in the speaker and mic at the same time?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, ffmpeg

List sound card info on my pc.

```
pacmd list-sources |grep name:
    name: <alsa_input.usb-SN0002-02.analog-mono>
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
```

Set variables to simply next command:

```
speaker=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
mic=alsa_input.usb-SN0002-02.analog-mono
```

Record a music playing on the speaker:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f pulse -i $speaker -acodec copy  /tmp/out.mkv
```

Record voice speaking to the mic:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f pulse -i $mic -acodec copy  /tmp/out.mkv
```

Now to record the sound both in the speaker and mic:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 \
    -f pulse -i $speaker -f pulse -i $mic \
    -acodec copy  /tmp/out.mkv
```

It output info on the screen:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, pulse, from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1606130053.472713, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, pulse, from 'alsa_input.usb-SN0002.analog-mono':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1606130053.597432, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

It record no voice speaking to the mic recorded  in `/tmp/out.mkv` ,only sound playing on speaker recorded?Why ffmpeg guess the Channel Layout for Input Stream?

I have tried the method on `superuser`:

https://superuser.com/questions/899352/ffmpeg-commandline-options-to-recording-audio-from-mic-and-speakers

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 \
    -f pulse -i $speaker -f pulse -i $mic   \
    -acodec libmp3lame -map 0:0 -map 1:0   /tmp/out.mkv
```

It record nothing ,both sound on the speaker and mic can't be recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's not possible to record audio from two sources at once. You have first to use [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic) to route audio from your microphone into the speakers and then record the mix of what you hear in the speakers.