# How to redirect LINE IN to LINE OUT?

Tags: 20.04, sound, games, hardware

I want to redirect the audio signal coming from my gaming console via LINE IN to my headphones which are connected to LINE OUT.
In Windows 10 I can select the LINE IN device in the sound options and select a target to redirect the signal but in Ubuntu I can't find that option.

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please check the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic

Comment: I checked this already. And it does not work for me. I can see the inline device in the recording (loopback) tab, but I can't select it for some reason.